# How to match WMS layer (point or polygon layer) with a Google Map base layer using OpenLayers?

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, wms

With OpenLayers, I'm trying to use a Google map layer as a base layer for a map which will display an overlay layer of custom data. My custom layer seems to have an offset related to the Google's layer and both have different projection values (as you may know google's projection is EPSG:900913, but mine is EPSG:32721)

Any ideas of how this match can be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you transform your custom data to EPSG:900913 before adding it to the layer?

Comment: Hi.. nop.. how do I do that? By the way, is it possible to match EPSG:900913 (google map layers) to my projection type? thanks!

Comment: `feature.geometry.transform(new Openlayers.Projection("EPSG:32721"), new Openlayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));`

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that your layer is a WMS you can't use OpenLayers functions to reproject data as it can only be used on vector data, not images.

One possible solution could be Cascading feature in Geoserver that would dynamically reproject your WMS to EPSG:900913. You can find more information about that [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/wms.html)